# Same linux kernel code as the one installed on the computer for adding the system call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

For adding a system call in linux, is it necessary that we download the source code of the same kernel version that we have on our computer? or can we download some other kernel version code and start modifying that code? If i can modify some other kernel code other than the one installed on my computer, how do i test it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,  you need to compile a modified kernel to add a syscall (you can't add a syscall with a kernel module).

So retrieve a recent kernel source from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/) and patch it to fit your need. You might want (on Debian or Ubuntu) to use `make-kpkg --initrd binary` to build it (then use `dpkg -i` on the obtained kernel header and kernel image `.deb` packages to install them).

You don't need exactly the same kernel as your computer has. You need a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding new syscalls is officially unsupported, although you can do this relative easily if you want.

For example, you can't develop kernel modules to create new syscalls, you need to patch some headers in include/linux and then recompile all.

Although there are/were independant projects they used a lot of different new system calls, for example reiserfs, grsecurity and yet a lot.

IMHO Linus and the core team has right when they say, new drivers & modules should use sysctls and ioctls as their interface to the user space, but maybe they are a little bit orthodox in this question.

If you modify something in the kernel, you need to port this modification everywhere. There is no binary compatibility in linux, only source compatibility (which has IMHO a good reason).